# execute drush command from devel/php drupal

Tags: 7, drush, debugging

Can any one please tell me how can I execute drush command from devel/php?

I can execute PHP codes from devel/php. But I don't know how can I execute drush command from devel/php. (As we know "devel/php" URL coming from devel module).

I have written some custom drush command for cron purpose. I can able to run those commands from command line.

```
> drush my-cmd or drush cc all or drush status , etc ... I can run it through command line.
```

Expecting some function as mentioned below to run from devel/php

```
some_function("drush cc all");
```

Answer (score 12):

Someone tried to create a module to provide shell access from within a Drupal site, but it was never fully debugged. See the [Drupal Terminal](https://www.drupal.org/project/terminal) project.  Perhaps there have been advances in the jQuery terminal that might make it easier to get this working if someone revisited it.

If you want to exec Drush from within php, it is generally better to use `drush_invoke_process()` rather than `exec("drush ...")`.

```
$values = drush_invoke_process("@site", "cc", array("all"), array("verbose"));
```

If you are just running a one-off command and you don't care about the command results, then `exec("drush ...")` is fine, though.

Answer (score 6):

As kalidasan suggests, you could use the exec() function, to do something like:

```
exec("drush fra -y", $output); var_dump($output);
```

Normally, devel will run this command where the settings.php is located, in case you have a custom multi-site architecture and you need to run the drush command from another path, you could chain commands (using ";" semi colon) to access to the right path and run the drush command:

```
exec("cd {absolute or relative path to your settings.php site}; drush fra -y;", $output); var_dump($output);
```

Sometimes, running drush commands from devel/php is useful when you need to execute functionalities from drush but you don't have access to the command line shell or permission to run it.

Note: I used "drush fra" only as an example, it could be used with any other drush command.

Answer (score 5):

Finally found solution. **shell_exec("drush status")** is working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Drush is a **command line shell** and **Unix scripting** interface for Drupal.

You **must** have **shell access** to execute the **drush** commands.

Comment: There is a way to do it from devel/php. I hope you know use of exec(). Similar way we can execute drush command through devel/php. I can't accept your answer.

Comment: ..AND the answer is...... `shell_exec()`

Comment: @sobi3ch Is it possible to make backup of the site and database using php code in devel? Please share the script. Considering this is the only option available to me. I cannot install backup_migrate module.