# Find drupal site root directory path

Tags: drush

We have hosted one of our Drupal 7 site at Acquia.

How do I find site root directory - `/mnt/www/html/mysite/docroot/`?

> I'm using [dpr(shell_exec("drush status"));](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127554/execute-drush-command-from-devel-php-drupal/127976#127976) command in devel/php

Is there anyother way to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DRUPAL_ROOT`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/install.php/constant/DRUPAL_ROOT/7).

It is defined in index.php as:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Krishna Mohan's answer, you can change directories to the root with:

```
cd `drush ev "echo DRUPAL_ROOT;"`; cd ..
```